# issues with multi-line cell wrap in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, cell

Am trying to create a multi-line cell in Excel through Apache POI. There are 10 columns. Here is my code. `str[i]` contains 10 values for 10 columns.

```
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                if(i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6) {
                    String impStr = str[i];
                    impStr = impStr.replace("\"", "");
                    impStr = impStr.replace("||", "\n");
                    String s[] = impStr.split("\n");
                    Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(i);
                    CellStyle cs = workBook.createCellStyle();
                    cs.setWrapText(true);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
                    cell.setCellValue(impStr);
                    currentRow.setHeightInPoints(s.length * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints());
                } else {
                    String tempStr = str[i];
                    tempStr = tempStr.replace("\"", "");
                    currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
                }
            }
```

I columns 3, 4, 5 and 6 have values delimited by `||` . The 6th column is important to me as it contains links separated by `||`. I have tried to replace `||` with `"\n"` and `"\r\n"`. I am not getting a wrapped cell. Instead I get only the last link. I am running this on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Re _"I get only the last link"_ Where do you get this? Looking at the sheet in Excel? Did you try to increase the cell height? If it is at default height (=1 line) you'll just see the last line of a multi-line cell.

Comment: Yes to the first Q....and I have set the height as you can see in the code just before the else statement.

Comment: Fixed it...impStr.split should come after impStr.replace(). But the problem now is, LibreOffice Calc opens it correctly. But Excel complains that there is a problem with the file and removes some of the formatting I had done.

Comment: I tried your code with an input of `str = { "A || B || C || D" };` and it worked. But LO (I don't have XL on this machine) showed the row with default height. So, the split() before replace() caused the row height not being set.

Comment: So, your first comment isn't completely correct, is it? You, or the code, did not set the height (I guessed it :) However, great that it's fixed.

Comment: It may be of help to others. A great post in my case it was a string line and had to do slightly different `row.setHeightInPoints(new Double(cell.split('\n').size() * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()).intValue())` notice it counts split size and also converts to double to get intValue since poi complained about double number